# Convert path alias to ID

Tags: views, commerce, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

How can I get the ID of a taxonomy term with only a path alias, using PHP?

I have a vocabulary with some taxonomy terms with a path alias like [vocabulary]/[term] (e.g. car/model) and I have repeated model terms. (So I think that using titles is not an option.)

I created a view with a path (car/%); if I want to make another view with an extra argument and car/%/% as path, I can't get the content unless I use the taxonomy ID like car/123/1 instead of car/model/cat.

Is there a way to make this?

Comment: I would suggest to use a parameter "?parameter=1" instead another argument in this case

Comment: can you explain me this a little more please? what do you mean?

Comment: You can keep using your taxonomy id and also a parameter, example: car/123?model=Toyota, is it a good option for you?

Comment: maybe that can work, but,  can i make a diferent views if a set the view path with something like car/model?cat=123 (will display products of model and cat 123) and other view with only path car/model to display subcategories? this because i want to use path alias instead of tid's because url's looks ugly lol. Also, you know if there is a way to get the tid with only a partial part of the path alias, e.g. get the tid of full path car/toyota-1 or car/toyota-0 with only the arg toyota-1 or toyota-0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this:

e.g. i have the path alias car/ilx-0 and i can get the tid easily, but what if i want to pass only the ilx-0 to another path view, like: products/ilx-0, the path alias doesn't match anymore so it's not easy to get the tid, to achieve that i used the following code on products/% view:

```
    <?php
    $pa=drupal_get_normal_path('car/'. arg(1, request_uri())); /* get the ilx-0 from products/ilx-0 and transform to taxonomy/term/tid */
    list($t1, $t2, $t3) = explode("/", $pa); /* Explode taxonomy/term/tid */
    /* $t1 = taxonomy */
    /* $t2 = term */
    return $t3; /* tid, return this value to get tid and pass to context filter*/
    ?>
```

Comment: Well done, it was kind of hard what you were asking sorry